# How to manually adjust system clock for testing purposes

Tags: raspbian, python, ntp, timekeeping, system-clock

I have written a Python script that is set to run different functions at different days/times. I would like to test it by setting the system clock to 1-2 minutes before the dates/times that the Python script is scheduled.

What is the best way to manually change the time on my Raspberry Pi?

Do I need to disable the NTP service? If so, how?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151547/linux-set-date-through-command-line

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? If so, consider posting an answer to your own question, I think it would be quite helpful to have an answer here. Thanks! Also, I have a slightly related question: [Recommended way for a python script to check NTP update status, and initiate an update if necessary?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/80219/35753)