# NTP is not enabled (doesn't exist) but Pi figures out timezone and time. How?

Tags: ntp

the `ntp` string isn't found in syslog. It's definitely not running. But when it has internet access, it has the right time. What's the mechanism?

This is on Raspbian Stretch minimal install.

Answer (score 7):

In Stretch the synchronisation is done using a systemd service (systemd-timesyncd.service) and a new program (systemd-timesyncd)

For time status information use `timedatectl`
For status information about the timesync service use

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
```

You will probably see the time has been updated at some point

More information is available with

```
man systemd-timesyncd.service
```

Comment: I see. This is a different question, but How could I force the time sync to happen in a script?

Comment: @Dirk: Good explanation - it's a question rattling around in the back of my mind for a while. But a closely related question (actually part of the OP's "subject" question) is this: How does RPi determine timezone? Is this done during installation?

Comment: @StevenLu Sorry, I don't know. I think it has come up on the RPi forum, but I can't find any relevant posts ATM

Comment: @Seamus The Raspbian images have the timezone preset to the UK. You would use the config utilities to change that (or do it manually of course). Latest Raspbian Desktop has the new setup utility that will ask for the timezone. It may do something automatically, but I would not notice because I'm in the UK timezone

Comment: OK then - that explains why I don't recall setting it - 'cause I never did :) I'm in the UK also, and I think I recall assuming that it must use some geolocation lookup to set it automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting an answer to augment @Dirk's answer, not to take exception. I believe @Dirk's answer is completely accurate, but it did pique my curiosity for details. I'm posting some of those details here as they may be relevant for some (including the OP).

As @Dirk mentioned, the `ntp` client was replaced with `systemd-timesyncd` beginning with the `stretch` distribution. It seems there were two motivations for this replacement:

1. some felt that [`ntp` was not an example of "good software"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47542/raspberry-pi-wont-update-time)
2. some felt that using a systemd-based time service was consistent with other changes being implemented in Linux

All well and good, yet [according to the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-timesyncd.service.html), there were some tradeoffs made:

> The systemd-timesyncd service specifically implements only SNTP. This minimalistic service will set the system clock for large offsets or slowly adjust it for smaller deltas. More complex use cases are not covered by systemd-timesyncd.

**SNTP** is the `Simple Network Time Protocol` defined by [RFC2030](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2030), which says in part:

> SNTP can be used when the ultimate performance of the full NTP implementation described in RFC-1305 is not needed or justified.

A [discussion of the diffs between NTP and SNTP can be found here](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/faq/faq_37.htm), which quotes another passage from RFC-2030:

> SNTP servers should operate only at the root (stratum 1) of the subnet and then only in configurations where no other source of synchronization other than a reliable radio or modem time service is available.

This should NOT be taken as a suggestion that the `systemd-timesyncd` timekeeping function in RPi is unsuitable. It is after all, a "hobbyist computer"... but then [so were Macs and PCs when they first arrived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_computer). And so there may be "serious" applications for Raspberry Pis that demand **NTP** over **SNTP**, or there may be other applications wherein the user wants or needs the ability to, for example, exercise control of the timekeeping function with a program or script[[1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80219/recommended-way-for-a-python-script-to-check-ntp-update-status-and-initiate-an), [2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72774/how-to-manually-adjust-system-clock-for-testing-purposes)]. In these cases, `systemd-timesyncd` may fall short.

If you fall into this category, and [feel `systemd-timesyncd` doesn't meet your needs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-16-04), you have at least three options:

1. install `ntp`; the client used on RPi prior to the **stretch** release, and maintained by the [Network Time Protocol project](http://www.ntp.org/)
2. install [`openntpd`](http://www.openntpd.org/); a client developed as part of the [OpenBSD project](https://www.openbsd.org/)
3. install [`chrony`](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/index.html); a project supported by [TuxFamily](https://www.tuxfamily.org/)

ArchLinux has documentation on [ntp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Time_Protocol_daemon), [openntpd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenNTPD) and [chrony](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrony) that may help you decide which best suits your needs. You may also wish to [review the docs for `timedatectl` available on ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time) before you make this change. All three packages are available for RPi, can be installed with the usual `sudo apt-get install X` [incantations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incantation).

<s>If you elect to install one of these **NTP** implementations, you could disable `systemd-timesyncd` as follows:</s>

```
$ timedatectl set-ntp false
```

However: As my colleague @Ingo has pointed out, this is not necessary since `systemd-timesyncd` checks for the presence of other **NTP** daemons, and will adjust its behavior accordingly; see `systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd`.

##### UPDATE/EDIT:

Debian (and therefore RPi OS) have changed the way that conflicts in timekeeping daemons are addressed. They are now addressed at the `apt package` level. IOW, if you are running `systemd-timesyncd`, and you try to install another timekeeping daemon (e.g. `chrony`), `apt` will only permit that if you first allow it to *un*-install `systemd-timesyncd`. REFS: [1](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#virtual-packages), [2](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/time-daemon), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/758103/286615)

Comment: There is no need to disable `systemd-timesyncd`. It will check if there is another NTP daemon installed. Check with `systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd´, bottom lines.

Comment: @Ingo: Brilliant! I'm confused though... that command `systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd` is an odd one! It lists 48 lines & stops... I've not found any way to get the rest of the file, and `man systemctl` is silent on that topic. As an aside, it seems that `systemctl` is in "takeovertheworld" mode  :)

Comment: On my default Raspbian `systemd-timesyncd` has 52 lines including copyright disclaimer and with `systemctl cat` it is opened in a pager (less) so you should be able to easily scroll down. And yes, `systemd` has already taken over the world. Everything from "the old stuff" is only emulated by systemd, even *fstab* (man systemd.generator).

Comment: Hmmm... the pager acts strangely for me. If I have a terminal window sized such that `lines 1-48` is displayed in inverse video at the bottom of my screen, then most of the "usual" keys terminate it, and take me to command prompt. However, if I resize my terminal window, the paging behavior becomes "normal". But yes, `systemd` is pervasive now... not sure I like that just yet, but we'll see.

Comment: @Ingo: This is done differently now (at least in Debian/RPi OS); see the edit.

Comment: Thanks, have noticed it.

Comment: Hello Ingo!  It's good to hear from you again - have you been keeping busy? Are you going to return to RPi SE???

Comment: *"Are you going to return to RPi SE?"* - Not really but I start to watching again a little bit of what's happening on SE. I'm still very busy with my UPnP project usable with RPis.

Comment: @Ingo: That's probably best... *start s-l-o-w*  :)  LOL   Seriously though, not much happening here it seems to me, but is still occasionally engaging. The volume definitely seems to have decreased since COVID, and the quality of the questions...  sheeesh! Anyway - so good to hear from you, and I hope you can make more time for us here.