# Raspberry pi4 does not synch to correct time after startup (ntp service running)

Tags: pi-4

After startup my RPI synchs to the correct date, but the time remains about 90 minutes off (behind).
sudo ntptime gives:

sudo ntptime

```
ntp_gettime() returns code 5 (ERROR)
  time e4e82bc8.c2d92000  Sun, Sep 12 2021  9:33:28.761, (.761126),
  maximum error 16000000 us, estimated error 16000000 us, TAI offset 0
ntp_adjtime() returns code 5 (ERROR)
  modes 0x0 (),
  offset 0.000 us, frequency -8.808 ppm, interval 1 s,
  maximum error 16000000 us, estimated error 16000000 us,
  status 0x4041 (PLL,UNSYNC,MODE),
  time constant 7, precision 1.000 us, tolerance 500 ppm,
```

systemctl status ntp gives:

```
* ntp.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-09-12 09:21:20 CEST; 15min ago
     Docs: man:ntpd(8)
  Process: 5516 ExecStart=/usr/lib/ntp/ntp-systemd-wrapper (code=exited, status=
 Main PID: 5522 (ntpd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
           `-5522 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 112:118

sep 12 09:34:32 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 38.229.58
sep 12 09:34:38 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 185.111.2
sep 12 09:35:36 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 23.157.16
sep 12 09:35:36 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 194.57.16
sep 12 09:35:37 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 2606:4700
sep 12 09:35:42 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 162.159.2
sep 12 09:36:40 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 216.229.0
sep 12 09:36:43 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 2a02:2b88
sep 12 09:36:43 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 78.202.24
sep 12 09:36:46 raspberrypi-OpenCPN ntpd[5522]: Soliciting pool server 185.89.20
lines 1-20/20 (END)
```

At the time of this check the actual time was 11:15 AM. Why does the time not sync correctly?

Comment: Is your timezone correct? Which OS/version? Or did you make any changes? PiOS doesn't use ntp service but `systemd-timesyncd`. For info you would use command `timedatectl`

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you have installed `ntp` instead of using RPi's default `sntp`? You may find [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/how-to-force-ntpd-to-update-date-time-after-boot/107344#107344) helpful - particularly some of the more current answers. And [this Q&A may give you some useful background](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87921/83790).

Comment: Timezone is correct, OS: Buster, latest upgrade. I disabled the default timesyncd and installed ntp service because I felt this a more generally used timeserver environment.

Comment: Solved: removed ntpd and reinstalled systemd-timesyncd